# Proguard Obfuscation of a fat jar containing POI library failing to run after obfuscation

Tags: java, jar, apache-poi, proguard, obfuscation

I am using progaurd to obfuscate my application classes which is fat jar containing the poi library. It run's as expected before obfuscation.

However I want to obfuscate only the application classes and not the other libraries present. To do so I am keeping the following lines in progaurd configuration file so as to avoid the obfuscation of the library classes.

```
-keep class org.apache.poi.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.poi.** { *; }
```

However after the obfuscation is completed the resulting obfuscated jar throws the following exception

```
<R ERRMSG="org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" STATUS="3"/>

org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)

org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:426)

org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:431)

org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:155)

org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:221)

org.pc.vr.VReport.a(VReport.java:355)

org.pc.vr.VReport.main(VReport.java:272)
```

The line 355 of my application class is

```
wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(xlsxFilePath));
```

This happens only after I have obfucated the jar , before obfuscation the jar works fine.

Following is my progaurd config file

```
-injars /home/syedammar/Desktop/VEJars/vr.jar
-outjars /home/syedammar/Desktop/VEJarsObfuscated/

-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-libraryjars /home/syedammar/Desktop/Library/poi-3.10/poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
-libraryjars /home/syedammar/Desktop/Library/poi-3.10/poi-excelant-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
-libraryjars /home/syedammar/Desktop/Library/poi-3.10/poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
-libraryjars /home/syedammar/Desktop/Library/poi-3.10/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
-libraryjars /home/syedammar/Desktop/Library/poi-3.9/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
-libraryjars /home/syedammar/Desktop/Library/poi-3.9/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
-libraryjars /home/syedammar/Desktop/Library/javacsv.jar
-libraryjars /home/syedammar/Desktop/Library/h2-1.4.177.jar
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/jce.jar

-printmapping /home/syedammar/Desktop/VEJarsObfuscated/vr.map
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature
-dontwarn
-dontnote 
-ignorewarnings
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames

-keep class org.openxmlformats.** { *; }
-keep class org.w3c.** { *; }
-keep class org.dom4j.* { *; }
-keep class org.dom4j.** { *; }
-keep class org.h2.* { *; }
-keep class org.h2.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.poi.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.poi.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.** { *; }

   # Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their     'main'
 # methods.
-keep public class org.pointcross.validationreport.ValidationReport {
 public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
 }

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

What could be the problem ? I need to have this jar as a fat jar.

Comment: Make sure you don't obfucate the Apache POI dependencies as well!

Comment: @Gagravarr I haven't obfuscated them. I am using  -keep class org.apache.poi.* { *; } to prevent its obfuscation.

Comment: That keeps the POI classes. Doesn't touch the dependencies!

Comment: dependencies are specified with -libraryjars so it should not obfuscate the dependencies right ? any other configuration setting for that ?